# Regex: get number after and before specific substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and trying to get number after substring `text` and before first non-numeric value.
I have:

`const str = 'fasdfsdanvczx fdasvczx text 321,fasdgasdf';
str.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp('text (.*)[^0-9]'));`

As a result I'm receiving:
`["text 321,fasdgasdf", "321,fasdgasd"]` but I want only `321`.

Thanks in an advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean like `\btext (\d+)\b` using a capturing group https://regex101.com/r/r0nwxP/1

Comment: Do you always expect the number to be the word immediately after `text`?  Can you include more sample inputs?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I always expect number after `text`. It just depends on separator after number, it could be dot, comma or empty space.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're using a greedy match `(.*)`. If you would've used `(.*?)` instead, it would've worked (doesn't mean it would work in every other situation). Thefourthbird's pattern is obviously more accurate because it's explicit about matching digits only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match the digits only in the first capturing group and use word boundaries `\b` to prevent `text` and the digits being part of a larger word.

Note to double escape the backslashes when using the RegExp constructor.

```
\btext (\d+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xjxwzj/1)

```js
const str = 'fasdfsdanvczx fdasvczx text 321,fasdgasdf';
let res = str.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp('\\btext (\\d+)\\b'));
console.log(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lookbehind to find number after 'text ':

```
(?<=text )\d+
```

Or simply match parts and select second group:

```
(text )(\d+)
```

Comment: Lookbehind is not available in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You may try splitting twice:

```js
var str = 'fasdfsdanvczx fdasvczx text 321,fasdgasdf';
var num = str.split(/text /)[1].split(/\D/)[0];
console.log(num);
```

The first spiit leaves us with `321,fasdgasdf`, and the second split discards everything from the comma onwards.